# Where and when can we skip "this" keyword in Lightning Web Components?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Putting `this` everywhere in Java code is a bad practice which reduces readability of code. The same is true with Javascript in Lightning Web Components.

But can we skip it like in Java or is there a technical reason why they are there all over in the documentation?

Comment: I don't think, that it is possible to skip usage `this` in JS, like in Java. Let's wait for answers from front-end ninjas. Meanwhile [this on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp)

Comment: I would slightly disagree that using `this` is considered a bad practice in Java. You will normally want to use `this` whenever you want to avoid shadowing. Also it depends on the standards that you may be following. E.g., I have seen some company explicitly requiring `this` keyword before any check-ins. Coming to JS, [`this` in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is entirely different than what is means in Java. The link  provided by @OleksandrBerehovskyi is a good starting point as how `this` changes its behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending my comments with some additional information (emphasis are all mine).

To start with, there is no similarity between Java and JavaScript except for the word "Java" in JavaScript. Both are two different languages serving different purposes.

As for the `this` keyword in two languages, below are some details.

---

By definition, [Using the `this` Keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) in Java is used:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the *current object* — the object whose method or constructor is being called

The documentation further mentions as below.

> The most common reason for using the `this` keyword is **because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter**.

In Java, you will always want to use `this` whenever you have a name conflict of variables/methods to avoid shadowing.

As for best practice, it usually depends on the coding practices that different organizations adapt and how frequently you use it. In my experiences with Java, I have seen people preferring to use `this` to explicitly call out if that was an instance variable vs. local variable. And some preferring not to have scenarios where there is a name conflict to avoid using `this`.

---

Coming to Javascript, `this` Keyword [the link provided by @OleksandrBerehovskyi](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) is a good starting point, which reflects the different behavior of the `this` keyword. There are other resources which will help you to understand the significance of `this` in Javascript specifically in ES6 modules used in LWC.

A very good mention about it is on the [Work with Classes](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/modern-javascript-development/work-with-classes) trailhead:

> In an attempt to make JavaScript at least appear to work like a class-based language, ES6 introduced the `class` keyword.
>
> ...
>
> What is important to know is that even though the `class` keyword is used, the **underlying object created is still a function**.

And then, the [official documentation for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on MDN mentions:

> A **function's `this`** keyword **behaves a little differently in JavaScript** compared to other languages.
>
> ...
>
> In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

The only time when you can skip using `this` in JS would be when you are say declaring local scoped variables. In all other cases you will end up using `this`.

Comment: Mentioning Java only confuses the topic, I think. Java is completely 100% unrelated to JavaScript except by name.

Comment: @sfdcfox I referred to Java in my question so talking about it in the answer is perfectly fine. Although they are not totally apples and pears... at some high level this in Java and in Javascript relate to the exact same concept.

Comment: `I have seen people preferring to use this to explicitly call out if that was an instance variable vs. local variable` - this is my practice preferring it over the `m_xxxx` prefix used in fflib

Answer (score 3):

This question is not specific to LWC but to JavaScript. Assuming you're specifically asking about ES6 class methods, `this.foo` and `foo` are very different things. A reference to `this.foo` evaluates to the instance property `foo`, whereas a reference to `foo` results in a scope chain lookup that goes all the way up to the global scope.

You should avoid building on top of your Java mental model when learning JavaScript because they are completely different under the covers.