# Struggling with basic Javascript in lwc: indexOf evaluation

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm passing a List called weekData from parent to child lwc that looks something like this: `['29','30','31','1','2','3,'4']`. It's a group of 7 dates, and I need to detect if this is first or last week of the month, so I'm doing an indexOf('1') on the list. If there's no '1', then I'll get -1 back. I can't seem to evaluate that value.

(The point of this is to dynamically assign a shaded background to dates that aren't in this selected month).

Here's the whole js...

```
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

const normalCss = "slds-size_1-of-7 slds-text-align_right slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom slds-border_left slds-p-bottom_xx-large slds-p-right_x-small";
const shadedCss = "slds-size_1-of-7 slds-theme_shade slds-text-align_right slds-border_top slds-border_right slds-border_bottom slds-border_left slds-p-bottom_xx-large slds-p-right_x-small";

export default class Week extends LightningElement {
    @api weekData;
    @api position; // first or last week of the month?
    cssList=[];
    index1 = weekData.indexOf("1");

    if(index1 != -1){
        if(position === "first"){   
            //shade dates up to that index
            for(let i = 0; i < index1; i++){
                this.cssList.add(shadedCss);
            }
            for(let i = index1; i < 7; i++){
                this.cssList.add(normalCss);
            }
        }else {
            // must be last row, shade dates starting with that index
            for(let i = 0; i < index1; i++){
                this.cssList.add(normalCss);
            }
            for(let i = index1; i < 7; i++){
                this.cssList.add(shadedCss);
            }
    }else {
        // not first or last row
        for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            this.cssList.add(normalCss);
        }
    }


    @api
    get sunDate() {
        return this.weekData[0];
    }
    @api
    get monDate() {
        return this.weekData[1];
    }
    @api
    get tueDate() {
        return this.weekData[2];
    }
    @api
    get wedDate() {
        return this.weekData[3];
    }
    @api
    get thuDate() {
        return this.weekData[4];
    }
    @api
    get friDate() {
        return this.weekData[5];
    }
    @api
    get satDate() {
        return this.weekData[6];
    }

    @api
    get sunCss() {
        return this.cssList[0];
    }
    @api
    get monCss() {
        return this.cssList[1];
    }
    @api
    get tueCss() {
        return this.cssList[2];
    }
    @api
    get wedCss() {
        return this.cssList[3];
    }
    @api
    get thuCss() {
        return this.cssList[4];
    }
    @api
    get friCss() {
        return this.cssList[5];
    }
    @api
    get satCss() {
        return this.cssList[6];
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the if(index1... line that says

> Parsing error, unexpected token. Expected ","

I'm still learning lwc, trying to understand when to use `this.` and whether I need to declare things as var or not.

Can you explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You seem to be missing the declaration using a `var`/`let` before using the variable `index1`.

Comment: @JayantDas that doesn't work. If I declare it as var or let, the evaluation (if line) clears the error, but now I get an error on the declaration itself. According to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_private I don't need a declaration for a private property.

Comment: You don’t have much code here to figure out anything further. If you can edit your question with at least what’s in your JS, that would help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be writing the business logic in the class body itself and thus you are encountering the error. As with most of the object oriented programming language, you will need to wrap the *logic/executable* portion in a function.

Your class along with a function will then look like as below:

```
export default class Week extends LightningElement {
    @api weekData;
    @api position; // first or last week of the month?
    cssList=[];

    // all logic currently written goes here
    myBusinessLogic() {

        // you will need to use let keyword to declare the variable here
        // you will need to use this keyword to be able to access the weekData public field
        let index1 = this.weekData.indexOf("1"); 

        if(index1 !== -1){
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I will also recommend to go through below resources for Javascript references:

- [Modern JavaScript Development trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/modern-javascript-development?trail_id=learn-to-work-with-javascript)
- [Javascript Classes documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Defining_classes)
- [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250507/54851) on significance of `this` in Javascript

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice regarding resources. I appreciate it!

Comment: @PatMcClellan__c You’re most welcome. Hope this provides you with some direction and the information you are looking for.